# Is there a way to set the value of an <input type=text...> with an ajax call like you can with a <select...>?

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to implement some save/load functionality on an HTML page I have by some ajax calls returning data from a database. Changing the value of a select drop down menu is done easily enough by having my PHP files return data as such...

```
//retrieve data
$sql = "SELECT Description
        FROM WorkSel1
        WHERE (AssignedEmp='$empname')";

$rs = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $data= odbc_result($rs, 'Description');
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option></div>",$data,$data);
}
```

This works easily enough just because I can send back some new drop down selections. However, when I just have something like

```
<input type='text' id='descript1'...></input>
```

Is there a way to change/set the value of it using a printf(...) call like is done here?

Just for the record the ajax call looks something like this...

```
function loadDescript(strURL) {    
var req = getXMLHTTP();
if (req) {
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
      // only if "OK"
      if (req.status == 200) {            
        document.getElementById('descript1').innerHTML=req.responseText;            
      } else {
        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
      }
    }       
  }     
  req.open("POST", strURL, true);
  req.send(null);
}
```

}

Comment: Use `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: What about the "value" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to

```
printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option></div>",$data,$data);
```

Just echo out your value like so:

```
echo $data;
```

and then in your calls success event do this:

```
document.getElementById('descript1').value = req.responseText;
```